# Metric is locally constant

Tags: riemannian-geometry, inner-products

If $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold.  My doubt is the following:

> For each $p\in M$, there is a coordinate chart $(U, (x_1,x_2,.., x_n))$ such that 
>   $g = \sum dx_i\otimes dx_j $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Locally, you can always find an orthonormal frame $\{X_1\ldots X_n\}$, but its vectors need not be coordinate vectors relative to a chart, because in general you will have $[X_i, X_j]\ne 0$. The property you state is equivalent to the manifold being *flat*.